# Issue with wrong command entered in fish-shell and it's output

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, fish

Actually I am using fish these days and I completely switched from bash to fish (with `chsh` & terminal startup command) but the matter is when I enter a wrong command e.g. `qwerty` its output is: `bash: qwerty: command not found...`
 since I switched to fish completely Why bash say that (instead of fish e.g. `fish: qwerty: command not found...`)?

*Also searched for it but no luck!*

Comment: What version of fish do you use? I reported this 3 years ago: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1918

Comment: Oops! I didn't think so but restart the session solved the problem and now I have 'fish:' instead of 'bash:'! fish version: 2.6.0. I am sorry guys! :)

Comment: @Cy8099 Welcome to SuperUser. The right way to show you’ve solved your own Question is to post your solution as an Answer, and then check the check-mark outline next to your own Answer to show you’ve accepted it as the right Answer.

Comment: Oh! I didn't no :0 sorry about that! Now I think I did it in a right way (but when I want to check my answer as a correct one it says: 'you can accept your own answer in 2 days') thank you anyway @Spiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restart the current session (by logging out and then back in) and that's all! issue has been sloved!

*Thanks for your comments guys :)*